# leetcode 139. Word Break

Tags: java

I am working on this question. It seems like that I have found the right answer and returns true but then it is overwritten by false.. Newbie in Java, sorry if it is a dummy question..   How do I just return true?
Thank you in advance

**Question** 
Given a string s and a dictionary of words dict, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

For example, given
s = "leetcode",
dict = ["leet", "code"].

Return true because "leetcode" can be segmented as "leet code".

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
public class Hi {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "leetcode";
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("leet");
    set.add("code");
    boolean b = wordBreak(str, set);
    System.out.println("b is " + b);
}

public static boolean wordBreak(String s, Set<String> wordDict) {
    if(s.length() == 0 || wordDict.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    return helper(s, wordDict, 0);
}

public static boolean helper(String s, Set<String> wordDict, int index) {
    if(index == s.length()) {
        System.out.println("1 is called.. ");
        return true;
    }
    int curIndex = index;
    System.out.println("curIndex is " + curIndex);
    while(index < s.length()) {
        //System.out.println("s.length() is " + s.length());
        curIndex++;
        if(curIndex > s.length()) {
            System.out.println("2 is called.. ");
            //return false;
            return false;
        }
        if(wordDict.contains(s.substring(index, curIndex))) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(index, curIndex) + " curIndex is " + curIndex);
            helper(s, wordDict, curIndex);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("3 is called.. ");
    return false;
}
```

**output:**
curIndex is 0

leet curIndex is 4

curIndex is 4

code curIndex is 8

1 is called..

2 is called..

2 is called..

b is false

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson You can just clicked the picture and it will be zoomed in.  Thanks.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I fixed it.. thank u for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question but I just mentioned an approach, and by no means I'm saying that my approach is better or more optimal.

In your code, there is no `return true` statement. The code does the right work but at the very end, since loop doesn't break anywhere, it always returns false. I mean you need to return true somewhere based on some condition and one of such conditions I mentioned in my below example.

```
private static boolean test(String str, Set<String> set) {
    int i = 1;
    int start = 0;
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (i <= str.length()) {
        String substring = str.substring(start, i);
        if (set.contains(substring)) {
            tokens.add(substring);
            start = substring.length();
        }
        i++;
    }

    String abc = "";
    for (String a : tokens) {
        abc = abc + a;
    }

    System.out.println(abc);

    if (abc.equals(str)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Below is the screenshot from debug trace from within debugger.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution but it might be more helpful if I could know what is the problem in my code. Thank you though.

Comment: I actually have "return true" statement but it is overwritten by "return false"

Comment: Yes! it's gets overwritten since you are calling helper() method recursively.

Comment: Yes! it's gets overwritten since you are calling helper() method recursively. In the end, it returns true but since a step before the last-step it returns false, and you don't consider the true returned in last step. I think you need to store the 'true' somewhere based on which you either break the loop or return 'true'. Anyway, I have added screenshot your debug trace from eclipse. See that your 'true' is the top most result but there are 2 more calls to 'helper()' method which would return false.

Comment: Thank u for the advice.. let me if I could fix it